# How to refer to the text of a shape in another page

Tags: vba, visio, shapesheet

I have two shapes, masterShape on the page Data and slaveShape on the page ESB. I mention that the Name & NameU of my pages are the same. I already read a lot about this ([See here for example](http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=8417.0)).

My goal is to make the text of slaveText equal to this of masterText.

I read a lot about referencing pages and fields, but seemingly not enough.

I start with the two shapes on the same page. When the two shapes are on the same page, I can assign a field to the slaveShape with this custom formula `=SHAPETEXT(masterShape!TheText)` so that it gives the expected result. Yes.

How to access this shape with a page reference?

I tried this:

- `=SHAPETEXT(ThePage!Softwares!TheText)` -> Error in formula (and should not meet the requirements)
- `=SHAPETEXT(Pages[Data]!Softwares!TheText)` -> Bad ShapeSheet Name

Yet this code in VBA gives the expected text:

```
Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Pages("Data").Shapes("Softwares").Text
```

Any idea to convert this VBA into a formula using `=SHAPETEXT(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use syntax with ID instead shape name. This syntax looks like

```
=SHAPETEXT(Pages[Data]!Sheet.740!TheText)
```

But you must find ID of master shape.

Comment: Thank for your help. Just for completion :  to find the ID :  Tab developper / Shape Name. But what's the point of being able to rename shapes then? So confusing for nothing ?

Comment: It is very useful rename sub-shapes into master-shape, it helps developer understand purpose of each sub-shape. But not good idea rename all shapes at page :)